# Trying to figure out how to only accept 1 character from user input

Tags: java, arrays, string, user-input

I'm not sure how to verify that the user only enters one character for input. I know that what I have for a length check is not correct at all. I simply used it for filler. Please help. I have tried numerous different ways and have searched this site and others for days in order to find an answer.

```
final char SIZE = 10;
char [] letter = new char [SIZE];
// initiallizing input device
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
for (char index = 0; index < SIZE;)
{
    System.out.println ("Please enter Letter #" + (index + 1));// gets letter from user
    while ((!scan.hasNext("[A-Za-z]+")) || (!scan.hasNext(length(1)))){
        if(!scan.hasNext(length (1))){
            System.out.println ("Please only enter one Letter at a time: ");
            letter [index] = scan.next().charAt(0); // accepts first character entered by user
        }
        if(!scan.hasNext("[A-Za-z]+")){
            System.out.println ("Please enter a valid Letter: ");
            letter [index] = scan.next().charAt(0); // accepts first character entered by user
        }
        else if((scan.hasNext("[A-Za-z]+")) && (scan.next(length(1)))){// makes sure letter entered is a letter
            letter [index] = scan.next().charAt(0); // accepts first character entered by user
            index++;// increases index if proper letter entered
        }
    }
}
for (char index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
{
    System.out.println ("Letter #" + (index + 1) + ": " + letter [index]);// prints characters entered by user in order
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be something like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter char");

String in  = sc.next();
while(in.length()!=1){
     System.out.println("Enter only a single char");
     in = sc.next();
}
// Print the read value
System.out.println("Your char is = " + in);
```

If you also want to check if it's a letter as opposed to a number, just add a check in the while loop for that.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. One way is what A.K. posted. One way is below:

```
for (char index = 0; index < SIZE;)
{
    String temp = scan.nextLine();

    if (temp.length() != 1)
    {
        // This means their input was too big
    }
    else
    {
        // This means their input was one character
    }

}
```

You can also use `scan.next().charAt(0);` This line of code will only take one character from the console as input.

If you have any questions or this answer isn't what you are looking for please comment below, I'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Input is only put on the buffer after the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, so it's always line-at-a-time in reality. You should always align your code with reality, so always read user input in *lines*.

This utility method may use useful:

```
private static String read(Scanner scanner, String message, String regex) {
    System.out.println(message);
    String result = "";
    while (true) {
         result = scanner.nextLine();
         if (result.matches(regex)) {
             break;
         }
         System.out.println("Invalid input. " + message);
    }
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
String letter = read(scan, "Please enter Letter #" + (index + 1)", "[A-Za-z]");
```

The `read()` method won't return until only exactly one letter is entered, and it will return that letter.